# Downloading an image from a certain link takes forever with urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to download images from a list of URLs that I've been given. Most of the links either return acceptable links or forbidden links. However, for a certain link, I am able to access it through a browser and it doesn't throw an error when the code attempts to download it. It just gets hung up and runs forever. Is this a problem with urllib, my code, or the link itself and is there a way around this?

```py
import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.mercedsunstar.com/news/9d6aao/picture82035257/alternates/FREE_640/13330875_1110997995625119_2134033517544198418_n", "test_image.jpg")
```

Comment: It's possible this site has auth that's hanging on a SYN response and your code is waiting/blocking until it receives a SYNACK (that'll never happen if you don't auth). Can you add any output from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This specific site is checking for the User-Agent and other headers browsers usually send. If these are not present it won't answer the request at all. Therefore your code is never returning. This mechanism is sometimes used to prevent automated crawling of images or other content, which is probably what your are trying to do.

You could look into the `build_opener()` and `install_opener()` methods of `urllib` to create an opener instance and modify its `addheaders` property before using `urlretrieve`.

```py
import urllib

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0")]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
```

After that the code from your question should work as is.

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.mercedsunstar.com/news/9d6aao/picture82035257/alternates/FREE_640/13330875_1110997995625119_2134033517544198418_n", "test_image.jpg")
```

If you're really crawling the web I would suggest you look into frameworks specifically designed to do that e.g. [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/). It offers many convenient functions that probably make it a lot easier to do what you're trying to achieve than building everything from scratch.

Also be advised that they might employ this mechanism for a reason and make sure that you are not infringing on their intellectual property rights.

Answer (score 0):

This page checks 'User-Agent' header to recognize web browser and blocks scripts and bots. `urllib` uses string like `"Python ..."` so server blocks it.

This code works for me

```
import urllib.request

req = urllib.request.Request('http://www.mercedsunstar.com/news/9d6aao/picture82035257/alternates/FREE_640/13330875_1110997995625119_2134033517544198418_n')
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0')

content = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
with open("test_image.jpg", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)
```